# How to debug a basic node.js application (not http) on windows

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I know how to debug http applications using node-inspector and iisnode. But can I use node-inspector to debug a *non http* node application, on windows?

I tried:

```
 node debug test.js
```

It says:

```
debugger listening on port 5858
```

But opening `http://localhost:5858/` in Chrome does not do anything.

---

BTW: running `node debug test.js` does start the command-line debugger which works. But it's nothing like node-inspector.

Comment: You could try http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/ debugger which is quite powerful

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To use node-inspector, the right switch is `node --debug` not `node debug`

Here are the detailed steps:

1. install node-inspector globally (`npm install -g node-inspector`)
2. from a command-line window, run: `node-inspector`
3. open Chrome and go to `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858`. You'll get the node-inspector UI but without any running app.
4. from another command-line window, run your app with the `--debug` switch like this: `node --debug test.js`
5. refresh the Chrome tab and *voila!*

A few interesting points:

- If you kill your app and start it again, just refresh the node-inspector tab. It will keep all your breakpoints.
- To break automatically on the first line start your app with `node --debug-brk test.js`

Comment: With the latest nodeJS on OSX, it seems that "node debug" does the right thing, and "node --debug" doesn't.

Comment: According to https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html the difference of either version is about what node is expected to do: `--debug` will start _some application to be debugged_ and `debug` will start node _to debug some application_. So these are two sides of the same story.

Answer (score 2):

Some links which might help you:

- http://vimeo.com/19465332 (screencast from Ryan himself).
- https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/using-eclipse-as-node-applications-debugger

Answer (score 2):

> It says: debugger listening on port 5858

I wondered myself about this but since the Node.js documentation indicates that the debugger is accessible via *a simple TCP protocol* and says nothing about HTTP my guess is that no, it won't be available at _http://localhost:5858.

"V8 comes with an extensive debugger which is accessible out-of-process via a simple TCP protocol" - http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

Comment: Good point about TCP vs HTTP. I know about the command-line debugger but it's really the node-inspector experience I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Very recently Microsoft released the [node.js tools for Visual Studio](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com). It has the very comfortable Visual Studio debugging for node.js.

Answer (score 0):

node-inspector could be very helpful.

Use it from any browser supporting websockets.

Breakpoints, profiler, livecoding, etc..

http://erickrdch.com/2012/09/debug-a-nodejs-app-with-chrome-dev-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

FYI, in OSX 10.8, Chrome v26 doesn't seem to work, but Safari 6 does using the same instructions as above and using 0.0.0.0:8080 to conect.

There is another post by Danny Coates somewhere that says to do it in the following order:

1. Your node process: node --debug (or --debug-brk) my_program.js
2. Node-inspector: node-inspector
3. The browser pointed to 0.0.0.0:8080

Answer (score 0):

If you are a noob like me on Windows, and you get 'node-inspector not recognized' or something about windows JScript error... despite global install, adding to PATH, etc. then this may help.

Navigate to C:\Users\urusername\AppData\Roaming\npm

Then run node-debug.cmd or node-inspector.cmd

You should get magical words like

```
Node Inspector v0.12.7
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?port=5858 to start debugging.
Debugger listening on port 5858
```

Awesome. If you know of a better solution, please let me know