# How can I debug a Sails.js app with node-inspector?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

In order to debug with `node-inspector` I need to start my app with the `node --debug` command.  Up to this point I have only used `sails lift` to start my Sails.js app, so I am unsure of how to start my app using the normal `node` command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug a basic node.js application (not http) on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437958/how-to-debug-a-basic-node-js-application-not-http-on-windows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Sails v0.10.x, you can do `sails debug` instead of `sails lift`.

Comment: Sails `0.10` or `0.11`?  Could you find the reference.

Comment: `sails inspect` for sails 1.0 and newer node: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49676411/895245 otherwise fails with https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4593 "DeprecationWarning: node --debug and node --debug-brk are invalid."

Comment: Thanks @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功, original answer failed for me. Your comment worked.

Answer (score 9):

So you can actually launch a `sails` project with `node app.js --debug` if you have `sails` installed in your project, rather than only system-wide.  Go to your project's root directory and run `npm install`.  Sails should already be in your `package.json` and thus should install to your project directory.

Comment: Note that there are more steps involved, like starting node-inspector: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11463248/168205

Answer (score 2):

**`sails inspect` since Sails v1.0**

As of sails v1.0, `sails debug` is deprecated for newer Node.js, and you should instead use `sails inspect`.

This is documented at: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-inspect and is presumably done to match the newer `node --inspect` interface.

Comment: Documented at: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-inspect This is presumably to match the newer `node -inspect`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) to run your node.js apps? This is what we use at work to debug our node.js server applications. It is quite useful runtime based on chromium which you can use to inspect your code using familiar breakpoints, stack traces, variable inspection and such without having to rely on node-inspector (which I find hard to use to be honest).

What you do is instead of using console command 'node you-app.js' you set the node-webkit to launch your app, run the webkit then open its console (which is the same as console in Chrome browser) and from there you can open your source files and start debugging like any other client side JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

**`node inspect`**

You can also use the command line debugger with:

```
node inspect app.js
```

This stops at the beginning, so do a continue:

```
c
```

And now, when your code with a statement:

```
debugger
```

gets executed, you fall into the Node CLI debugger as usual.

Tested on Sail v1.1, Node v10.15.1, Ubuntu 18.10.

**`nodemon --inspect` and `nodemon inspect`**

You can use those to inspect when using `nodemon`, which automatically reloads the app on file save: [Auto reloading a Sails.js app on code changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687818/auto-reloading-a-sails-js-app-on-code-changes)

Those options are analogous to `node inspect` and `node --inspect`: `node inspect` works with `debugger` statements, and `node --inspect` works with the Chrome debugger.

Especially useful with the "Open dedicated DevTools for Node" feature: [Can I get node --inspect to open Chrome automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398970/can-i-get-node-inspect-to-open-chrome-automatically)

`nodemon inspect` is a bit annoying as it requires a `continue` everytime you make any app changes and `nodemon` restarts the server. TODO find a way around it.