# Can I get node --inspect to open Chrome automatically

Tags: node.js

In the new versions of node, node-inspector is built in and can be fired using the command `node --inspect index.js`. However, this always provides a command line with the address you have to plug into the address bar. I know this may not be the most "secure" but is there a way to eliminate that copy and paste step?

Comment: Have you learned how to do this? I'm looking for the same answer. I use nodemon with webpack hot reload at I loose the inspector connection all the time.

Comment: @AdrianMoisa take a look at  my answer.

Comment: http://june07.com/nim
http://june07.com/inspect-broke-my-workflow Stated already but this tool does the job well.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In Chrome 60+ there is an item **"Open dedicated DevTools for Node"** in `chrome://inspect/#devices` url, (as well as Node.js icon in DevTools while Node is running). The opened inspect window will connect to Node.js as soon as it starts or restarts, so there is no need to open it manually each time.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! It's awesome, that there is a built-in debug support for node.js. Brilliant.

Comment: @Zoltan your welcome, I think it's introduced in version 57.

Comment: This is great but is there a way to disconnect dev-tools from the process once it ends? At the end of my process I get `Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...` on the console and have to `Ctrl + c` or close the dev-tools window for it to return.

Comment: @ChrisR I don't get such a message in Intellij.

Comment: Can pair this with nodemon too, pass the `--inspect` flag to through to node: `nodemon -- --inspect`

Comment: Chrome Canary is currently not available on the Linux platform.

Comment: @Toolkit, the current version of chrome is 61

Comment: In Chrome 73 inspector won't re-connect automatically. Works only with chrome://inspect. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143498/chrome-73-can-no-longer-debug-nodejs-with-dedicated-devtools-for-node

So maybe NIM is the best solution for now.

Answer (score 8):

I was searching an answer for the same problem and I discovered two nice tools:

- [Node inspector Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nim-node-inspector-manage/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj/reviews?hl=en)
- [Node.js V8 Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector/lfnddfpljnhbneopljflpombpnkfhggl)

NIM seems more advanced, it's able to auto-detect node instances which plays very nice with my current setup. I use `nodemon` to automatically restart node server whenever a file is changed. Even further than this I setup Webpack with HMR (Hot module reload) and I have total coverage of `/public` and `/server` folders. It took me 2 weeks to learn how to setup but now it's starting to pay off.

```
npm install -g nodemon
npm install -g ts-node // In case you use typescript
```

**nodemon.json**

```
{
    "verbose": false,
    "watch": ["server/**/*.ts"],
    "ext": "ts js json",
    "ignore": ["server/**/*.spec.ts"],
    "exec": "set DEBUG=app:*,-not_this & ts-node --inspect --debug-brk server/main.ts"
}
```

`set DEBUG=app:*,-not_this` is used to enable output from [Visionmedia debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug)

(!) Currently there is [an issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/424) with `debug()` not printing text in chrome inspector, However for the moment at least the text is visible in the command line. I use command line to see the debug statements and inspector to expand objects.

**Edit**

Meanwhile I found a rather ugly fix but I does the job, partly... Color metadata is ignored and worse it's rendered in the strings. So it's badly affecting the readability. But hey... I got some logs coming out, better then nothing.

Another issue I had recently is that NIM was not connecting properly. Eventually I figured out that I need to input the actual IP address `127.0.0.1` in NIM config panel instead of `localhost`

`debugOff` it's just an improvised way to have logs closed temporarily until I need them back again.

```
// Debug
let debugOff = (...any: any[]) => { }, debug = require('debug')('vs:ServerApp');

// Workaround for debug working with node inspector in chrome
let Debug = require('debug');
Debug.log = console.log.bind(console);


/** 
 * Listen for incoming requests
 */
public listen(): void {
    debug('Start server');
    debugOff('Server port:', SERVER.port); // This would be usually too verbose
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a separate utility to do this called [inspect-process](https://github.com/jaridmargolin/inspect-process), but no in built support.

As far as I can see, the (C++) code that is starting the inspector and outputting that debug message is here:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/inspector_socket_server.cc

Specifically the functions, `InspectorSocketServer::Start`, `PrintDebuggerReadyMessage`

I don't see any feature to auto open a browser in this code (at the time of writing v7.4) but would suggest one of the following:

1. open a feature request here https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues
2. implement the feature yourself and submit a PR
3. use [inspect-process](https://github.com/jaridmargolin/inspect-process)

Comment: It's working. debug-brk works too.
inspect --debug-brk index.js

Answer (score 4):

Yes!! Use [Node.js V8 --inspector Manager (NiM)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj/reviews?hl=en) Chrome plugin, it opens Chrome automagically when I run `node --inspect-brk app`

On a side note - debugging with Visual Studio Code has become a breeze

Answer (score 3):

For OSX users, install the amazing [chrome-cli](https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli) with `brew install chrome-cli`.

Put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
node-inspect() {
  local TAB_ID=`chrome-cli open 'chrome://inspect/#devices' -n | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $2 }'`
  sleep 0.5
  chrome-cli execute "document.getElementById('node-frontend').click()" -t $TAB_ID && chrome-cli close -t $TAB_ID
  node --inspect-brk $@
}
```

Now you can do: `node-inspect ./server --foo --bar`

Comment: Boo for Homebrew... If it don't make I don't take

Comment: Note that for `chrome-cli execute` to work, you need to allow JavaScript from Apple events. See https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli#javascript-execution

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't *specifically* answer the question, it makes the question less relevant - once connected you don't need to reconnect.

I tried all the suggestions here and other posts [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853443/how-can-i-make-node-inspector-restart-when-node-is-restarted) but I found the debug-in-a-tab would never reconnect once supervisor watch had generated a new GUID - the address in the tab is out of date.

However I found a new link in Chrome (58) standard Developer Pane which opens a new "headless" window which does reconnect magically no matter how the app is rebuilt / restarted.

Under Threads > Main, you should see "Node instance available. Connect".[image]

I find the new-window less usable as I'd prefer a tab, but the auto-reconnect is so reliable I'll live with that!

The only downside I've found is when it does reconnect it clears all breakpoints.

UPDATE: 
I’ve found it’s possible to workaround the problem of the breakpoints vanishing on reload, if you open several debug windows using the “Connect” link under Chrome Debug > Sources > Threads > Main. Most of them will be blank and won’t even have any sources listed in them, but the one that’s properly connected will eventually retain its bookmarks. I don’t know why this hack works — I discovered it by mistake.

Also [this Hackernoon article](https://hackernoon.com/debug-node-js-with-chrome-devtools-aca7cf83af6b) discusses the problem, and [the tool NIM](http://june07.com/nim) is recommended as a solution, and general improvement to managing the inspector (also suggested in the answer by Adrian Moisa).

**Update (08/2017)**

It seems Chrome v60 has changed the DevTools for Node, moving the link I described to a small green box icon in the top left nav-bar of the JS dev tools.
[image: Node Devtool icon]

However now my breakpoint hack no longer works as you can no longer open multiple windows. Sadly they've not fixed the disappearing breakpoints issue either. So now I'm back to closing it and reopening it every time... This is extra annoying as it doesn't even remember its window position (I like to move it to differentiate it from the front-end JS debug window which I use simultaneously being full-stack...), nor the fact I've close all those source file tabs already (I'll stop ranting now).

Answer (score 2):

Now in modern chrome *(I have v64, don't know about lower versions)*, typing

```
chrome.send('open-node-frontend')
```

in the chrome console open a window that automatically connect to nodejs process
*(also accessible via `chrome://inspect`)*

You can also start and close the inspector programatically
*(see the doc https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/inspector.html)*

Or using `kill -USR1 $PID` where `$PID` is your node process pid
*(but I don't know how to stop it, and it's not possible to specify host and port, it will use `localhost:9229`)*

Comment: the active tab must be `chrome://inspect` for `chrome.send` to work

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, for multiple reasons.

1. Starting the Chrome (or other "desktop" application) is platform dependent. Core Node can't do it and it would add unnecessary complexity (e.g. think about discovering the install location, dealing with Chrome not installed, etc).
2. This would tie Node to Chrome, which is not desirable.
3. Chrome does not provide a way to pass devtools URL from the command line.

Comment: What you're saying is completely right, but answers a totally different question. Instead of letting Node handle spawning Chrome instances, we can make Chrome discover active Node sessions.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install express
npm install esm
npm install open
npm install --save-dev node-key-sender
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "open-browser",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "browser",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "esm": "node -r esm server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "open": "^7.0.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-key-sender": "^1.0.11"
  }
}
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import http from 'http'
import open from 'open'
import keysender from 'node-key-sender'

const webApp = express()
const webServer = http.createServer(webApp)

webServer.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('> Server listening on port:',3000)
  open('http://localhost:3000')
  keysender.sendCombination(['control', 'shift', 'i'])
})
```

the browser must already be open, then run

```
node -r esm server.js
```