# Chrome 73: Can no longer debug NodeJS with Dedicated DevTools for Node

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've just upgraded my Chrome to 73.0.3683.75 (Linux) and now cannot get my dedicated Node debugger to actually debug a running instance. Even though I can see the "Debugger attached" message in the console:

```
$ node --inspect-brk hello.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/864a1c18-5e45-49ab-843c-77a22841ffff
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
```

the debugger window does not show any signs of debugging a target:
[image: Dedicated Node debugger window]

Anyone has an idea if this is broken in Chrome 73 or if I'm doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome, however invoking from chrome://inspect works for me.

Comment: same issue on windows7

Comment: @wOxxOm: Right, forgot to mention that just clicking the "inspect" link for the respective target works fine.

Comment: Works just fine for me on 72, 73 and ToT 75. Could that be specific to a node version? Mine is 11.1.0

Comment: @alph: Mine is v10.13.0 and it's the same with 11.11.0 for me.

Comment: Just a heads up, if you have the nodejs debugger open and pressing inspect it won't work. You need to close the nodejs debugger first before opening from chrome://inspect. Wasted 30 mins trying to figure out it won't connect even when using chrome://inspect

Comment: @LeonHo: What exactly do you mean by "nodejs debugger"? Also, what kind of debugging from chrome://inspect have you been trying out? The dedicated node debugger or the "inspect" link?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Sorry what i meant was the "Dedicated dev tools for node". If you left the "dedicated dev tools for node" open and then press on the inspect link afterwards the inspect link won't connect to the running node application. I forgot that i left the dedicated dev tool running in the background hence why the inspect link didn't work.

Comment: @alph Confirmed not working for me either... Chrome v73.0.3683.75, node v10.13.0, MacOS 10.13.16

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it's a bug with v73. I am also seeing it

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=941608&q=nodeJS

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

This bug was fixed in chrome 74.0.3729.61 [check here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=941608#c32)

---

you might use [ndb](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb) which is tailored for node.js and also from GoogleChromeLabs.

install using

```
npm install -g ndb
```

Usage:

Use ndb instead of node command:

```
    ndb server.js
    # Alternatively, you can prepend `ndb`
    ndb node server.js
```

Prepend ndb in front of any other binary:

```
    ndb npm run unit
    ndb mocha
    ndb npx mocha
```

Launch ndb as a standalone application:

```
    # cd to your project folder (with a package.json)
    ndb .
    # In Sources panel > "NPM Scripts" sidebar, click the selected "Run" button
```

if you are using nodemon:

```
 ndb nodemon .
```

for further details see the project github repository

https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb

Comment: ndb@1.0.26 is working for me, later versions didn't (see issues/204)

Comment: This bug was fixed in chrome 74.0.3729.61