# Chrome DedicatedTools stopped working for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a Node.js (ExpressJS) app launched like this:

**package.json**

```
  ..
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --inspect dist/server.js"
  },
  ..
```

Log output:

```
./manage.sh start-api-server
Starting Docker MySQL server
floralle-mysql
Starting Node.js API server
yarn run v1.13.0
$ nodemon --inspect dist/server.js
[nodemon] 1.18.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node --inspect dist/server.js`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/ac59f7ff-5315-4f09-8754-7cd774530f3e
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Server up! Listening 3030.
Debugger attached.
```

Chrome (chrome://inspect/devices#devices) sees it:

[image]

However clicking *Open dedicated DevTools for Node* stopped seeing any events. I can click on the *Inspect* and see the events, however since nodemon rebuilds the server on each change - it becomes useless.

Everything worked fine until I changed the target discovery settings..

My current items are:

- localhost:9229
- localhost:9222

Any clues how to make *Open dedicated DevTools for Node* hear the Node again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this to happen is a Chrome 73 bug: [Chrome 73: Can no longer debug NodeJS with Dedicated DevTools for Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143498/chrome-73-can-no-longer-debug-nodejs-with-dedicated-devtools-for-node).

The issue seems to be given a high priority (release blocker) and hopefully will be fixed soon.

For now, the work-around is to stay with the *Inspect* and reload the debugger or use an alternative solution.