# How to use node-inspector with sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, sails.js

I would like to debug my sails.js application but I don't know how to launch `node-inspector` for this occasion.

Normally it would go :

```
$ node --debug myapp.js
```

If I run my sails application normally :

```
$ sails lift --prod
```

and then launch `node-inspector`

```
$ node-inspector --debug-port 1337
Node Inspector v0.7.0-2
   info  - socket.io started
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=1337 to start debugging.
```

I get this error in inspector GUI :

```
Error: read ECONNRESET. Check there is no other debugger client attached to port 1337.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug a basic node.js application (not http) on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437958/how-to-debug-a-basic-node-js-application-not-http-on-windows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct me if im wrong but, you cant use debug port 1337 if sails lifts on port 1337.

try specifying a different port.

```
node --debug app.js
#this will lift sails on port 1337 and the default debug port i think its 5858
#start node-inspector, once it starts hit enter to put it into background
node-inspector &;
#visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858
```

**edit** just confirmed this method works, instead of using `sails lift` you're using node to start `app.js` in debug mode. the node-inspector web runs on port `8080` and the debugger links on port `5858` by default.

Comment: it'd be great if there was a flag available in sails to enable debug mode.. Im going to poke around a bit.

Answer (score 11):

As of Sails 0.9.8 you can use `sailsd` to call sails in debug mode, e.g. `sailsd lift`.

-- Edit --

Looks like this didn't actually make it into 0.9.8, my bad.  To make your own debugging command for now, save the following into `/usr/local/bin` as `sailsd` (or whatever you like):

```
#!/bin/sh
node --debug `which sails` $@
```

-- Edit 2 --

In Sails v0.10.x, you can do `sails debug` instead of `sails lift` to start Sails in debug mode!

Comment: I cannot find `sailsd` on my system.

Comment: My bad--I thought we had put it into 0.9.8.  Edited with info on how to create `sailsd`.

Comment: v10 docs: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/Command%20Line/sailsdebug.md

Comment: sails debug worked for me... this should be the correct answer